# Android: LinearLayout Weight

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to make my layout a bit more uniform. I have a linear layout that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblQuote" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
           <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblLikes" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="4pt"
                android:text="27"/>
           <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgUp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/thumbsup"/>
           <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblBuzzedTitle" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="4pt"
                android:text="Buzz Level:"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblShared" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="4pt"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblSaid" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="4pt"/> 
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
          <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblHates" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="4pt"
                android:text="14"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgDown"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/thumbsdn"/>
           <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblBuzzed" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="4pt"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblDate" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="4pt"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblLocation" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="4pt"/> 
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
          <TextView
            android:text=" "
            android:textSize="1pt"
            android:background="#6F7285"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>  

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So I've switched to this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblQuote" 
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:weightSum="8">
           <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblLikes" 
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="4pt"
                android:text="27"/>
           <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgUp"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/thumbsup"/>
           <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblBuzzedTitle" 
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textSize="4pt"
                android:text="Buzz Level:"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblShared" 
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textSize="4pt"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblSaid" 
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textSize="4pt"/> 
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:weightSum="8">
          <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblHates" 
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="4pt"
                android:text="14"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgDown"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/thumbsdn"/>
           <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblBuzzed" 
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textSize="4pt"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblDate" 
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textSize="4pt"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblLocation" 
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textSize="4pt"/> 
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:weightSum="1">
          <TextView
            android:text=" "
            android:textSize="1pt"
            android:background="#6F7285"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>  

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Upon doing that my layout goes blank in the emulator. Please advise. I do not want to switch to Relative layout I just want to know what I'm doing wrong with this bit of code. Thanks.

#

Edit 6/3/2011:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblQuote" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Filler Text"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left">
           <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgUp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/thumbsup"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>
           <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblLikes" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="4pt"
                android:text="10"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>

           <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblBuzzedTitle" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textSize="4pt"
                android:text="Buzz Level:"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblShared" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Shared By: Filler Name"
                android:textSize="4pt"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblSaid" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Said By: Filler Name"
                android:textSize="4pt"/> 
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgDown"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/thumbsdn"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>
          <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblHates" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="4pt"
                android:text="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>

           <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblBuzzed" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="High"
                android:textSize="4pt"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblDate" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textSize="4pt"
                android:text="04/04/1987 4:32 PM"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lblLocation" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textSize="4pt"
                android:text="Broomfield, CO"/> 
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1">
          <TextView
            android:text=" "
            android:textSize="1pt"
            android:background="#6F7285"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>  

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: A quick scan tells me it looks the same? Where were the changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second version, your first nested LinearLayout has a layout_height of fill_parent. That pushes everything else down off the screen. Whenever you see yourself using layout_weight when you are also using fill_parent for both width and height, then you know that you are doing something wrong.

What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

By the way, you don't need to use weightSum the way you are doing. If you don't specify it, it will automatically sum up the layout_weight values of all the child views. It's main use is to distribute only a fraction of the total extra space available.

Comment: and to add to Ted's response, why exactly are you setting the `layout_width` to `0dp`?

Comment: So I've replaced fill_parent with wrap_content on all of my Linear layouts. The same result occurs. I appreciate the speedy response you've given so far. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I've found the [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-ui.html) tool useful for diagnosing these kinds of problems. (I'd rather be giving you a solution rather than advice here, but I'm half asleep and headed for bed.)

Comment: Anirvan: Thanks for the tip. Replacing the width with wrap_content did the trick.

This is all but completely solved my problem. The main thing I'd like now is for the 1st two columns to always align. So lblHates and lblLikes to align and imgHates and imgLikes to align. Right now they are moving around quite a bit. Please advise.

Comment: Could you update your post and include an image of what it looks like, what you want it to look like, and the xml as it is now? Also, I don't see imgHates and imgLikes in your layout; did you mean imgDown and imgUp?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Thanks for the correction. I'll get that info up to ya as soon as possible.

Comment: I've made the changes. Let me know what ya think.

Comment: And before you ask the images are the same dimensions, the red one is not wider. Wish it were that simple though.

Comment: At a first glance, I would suggest changing the image and the likes/hates views to have `layout_weight="0"`. Use padding to get the spacing you want for them. Then the first two columns will have fixed width (based only on the image and text sizes and the padding) and all the extra space will be distributed to the other two columns.

Comment: P.S. I also think that this could all probably be done a little more directly using a single RelativeLayout. I'll see if I can gin up something if my above suggestion doesn't work for you.

Comment: I'll try, but I am still open to the RelativeLayout! I really was just so fed up with myself that I couldn't get it to work that I wanted to know what the problem was and how to fix it rather than avoid it and move to something else. Now that I know the problem I'm game for improvement suggestions. The problem I've had with Relative layouts is I'm inflating the layout in a loop in my activity and all the text stack on top of each other when using the inflater but they don't when I'm not. The layout will look perfect upon testing then I place the layout int he inflater and they're stacked.